# C# Installing Windows 10 Feature Update using wuapi

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-10

I'm trying to use the WUAPI to install the latest Windows 10 feature update. For some reason, the feature update is not listed in the results after searching for missing updates. Tested on multiple computers running < 2004 (all on 1903). All computers list the feature update available in the Windows Update GUI, however, this update does not show up in the WUAPI query.

```
using WUApiLib;

UpdateSessionClass uSession = new UpdateSessionClass();
IUpdateSearcher uSearcher = uSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
uSearcher.Online = true;
ISearchResult uResult = uSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 or IsInstalled=1");
```

Not sure if i'm missing something here or if performing feature updates is not possible using WUAPI. If not, does anyone have any reliable alternatives to install the Windows 10 feature updates?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running this in a corporate domain?  They might have their own WSUS blocking certain updates

Comment: No, no WSUS. These are standalone workstations